# Attempting to add food object to array causing crash Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to swift and MVC. I'm getting html and parsing that to create a list of foods in season, which is working correctly. 
I'm then trying to create food objects of each food and add them to a list of foods. I can create the food object but when I try to add them to the list of foods I get the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my model:

```
import Foundation

class food {
    var foodImageName: String = ""
    var foodName: String = ""

    init(fn: String)  {
        foodName = fn
        foodImageName = "FreshFruitAndVeg.jpg"
    }
}

class foodList  {
    var listOfFoods:[food]

    init()  {

        listOfFoods = []
    }

    func add(foodType:food)    {
        self.listOfFoods.append(foodType)
        print("Food added!")

    }

    func delete(rowNum: Int)    {
        self.listOfFoods.remove(at: rowNum)
    }
}
```

In my FoodsViewController I get the current month and determine the currentSeason and the nextSeason from that. I arrange the html tags into an array which contains a lot of extraneous information, so I find the index of both the currentSeason and nextSeason elements. Once I have that information I run a for loop using those indices to create a food object and add it to  myFoodList. I can see that the food objects are being created and I can print out the contents, but when I attempt to add it to myFoodList it gives the error described above.

I create my variables inside the FoodsViewController like this:

```
var currentSeason = ""
    var nextSeason = ""
    var currentSeasonIndex = 0
    var nextSeasonIndex = 0
    var endIndex = 0

    var myFoodList: foodList!
```

Here is the code snippet where I create the food object and try to add it to the foodList
:

```
do  {
     for i in currentSeasonIndex+1..<nextSeasonIndex   {
           let text = try nextElements[i].text()
           print("This season's foods: ", text)
           let newFood = food.init(fn: text)
           print ("New food to be added: ", newFood.foodName)
           myFoodList.add(foodType: newFood)
           for item in 0..<myFoodList.listOfFoods.count   {
                    print("My food List: ", myFoodList.listOfFoods[item])
            }

       }
 }
 catch   {

 }
```

I can see in the debugger that the food object is there, but myFoodList is always nil causing a crash at the line

```
    myFoodList.add(foodType: newFood)
```

I've been reading about the error and basically understand that it is expecting a value of some some, but there is nothing there, hence the nil which I can also see in the debugger.
I though maybe I needed to initialize the object with the init() function but that just causes errors in compilation

I can't figure out why this add function is causing this problem. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: start class names with capital letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
var myFoodList: FoodList!
```

is `nil` if you don't init it. So first you need

```
var myFoodList = FoodList()
```